# LINQ operation with ternary operation causing tests to fail if logic is swapped

Tags: c#, linq

So I am using LINQ to evaluate a string and use the Regex library to either parse a string that is a digit or any other character returns 0. If I swap the logic, it should still work either way but it doesn't... below is an example of the two scenarios.

> This example is the one that allows for my tests to pass.

```
return Regex.Split(number, @"[^\d-]")
            .Select(d => Regex.IsMatch(d, @"[\d-]") ? int.Parse(d.TrimEnd('-')) : 0)
            .Where(d => d <= 1000).ToList();
```

> Logic swapped, it should pass still, but causes a couple of my tests to fail...

```
return Regex.Split(number, @"[^\d-]")
            .Select(d => Regex.IsMatch(d, @"[^\d-]") ? 0 : int.Parse(d.TrimEnd('-')))
            .Where(d => d <= 1000).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you provide the exception that  you're getting?

Comment: `IsMatch` just makes sure that your expressions exists somewhere.  So a value like "A1" would match both `[\d-]` and `[\d-]` because it has a digit and it has a value that is not a digit or a dash.

Comment: The exception being thrown is a parsing exception, d is not in the correct format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't actually swapping the logic in your second line of code. To fully swap the logic, you would need to negate the `if` statement like so:

```
return Regex.Split(number, @"[^\d-]")
            .Select(d => !Regex.IsMatch(d, @"[^\d-]") ? 0 : int.Parse(d.TrimEnd('-')))
            .Where(d => d <= 1000).ToList();
```

Adding the `!` before `Regex.IsMatch(d, @"[^\d-]")` will give you everything that is NOT a valid digit and return a value of 0.

Comment: That was it! My mind is a mess... thanks for the help!